# How to partition by in pandas and output to a word doc?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a table I have filtered from data. It is my highlights across the web. I want to, ultimately, output these to a doc file I have by the page they came from

I have the api data filtered down to two columns

url|quote

How do I, for each url, output the quote to a doc file. or just for starters iterate through a set of quotes by each earl.

In SQL it would be something like this

Select quote over(partition by url) as sub_header
From table

url quote
https://jotengine.com/transcriptions/WIUL8HBabqxffIDOkUA9Dg I actually think that the bigger problem is not necessarily having the ideas. I think everyone has lots of interesting ideas. I think the bigger problem is not killing the bad ideas fast enough. I have the most respect for the Codecademy founders in this respect. I think they tried 12 ideas in seven weeks or something like that, in the summer of YC.

https://jotengine.com/transcriptions/WIUL8HBabqxffIDOkUA9Dg We were like what the heck is going on here so we went and visited five of our largest customers in New York, this was about three years ago and we said okay, you're using the S3 integration but what the heck are you using it for? For five out of five customers in a row, they said well we have a data engineering team that's taking data from the S3 bucket, converting it into CS view files and managing all the schema-translations and now they're uploading it into a data warehouse like Redshift. The first time I heard that from a customer, I was like okay, that's interesting

I want to output a url header followed by all the quotes I've highlighted. Ideally my final product will be in docx

Answer (score 0):

it would be great if you could provide some source code to help explain your problem. From looking at your question, I would say all you need to do is put your columns into a DataFrame, then export this to excel.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"url":url,"quote":quote})

df["quote"].to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

Hope this helps.